# Wire peltier device and fan to power supply

Tags: power-supply, connector, peltier

I have 6 12v, 6 amp, 60 watt peltier devices and 3 12v, 0.08 amp fans that I want to connect to a 12v, 40 amp, 480 watt power supply. This guy over here:
https://www.banggood.com/AC-110V-220V-TO-DC-5V-12V-24V-2A10A15A20A40A60A-Switch-Power-Supply-Adapter-p-1191491.html?rmmds=cart_middle_products&cur_warehouse=CN

I'm an absolute newbie when it comes to electronics so I would first like to know whether that power supply is right for the job?

If it is right for the job, my next step is to wire the components to the power supply. This is where I'm having trouble moving forward. I assume I can't just jam all the wires into the 12v lines and turn it on, but I would rather need to find a way to split the output for the 6 peltiers and 3 fans and provide special connectors for them. What would this all entail? Are there products available for this or is this something I would need to build from scratch myself?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have more or less the right idea, absurd as it may sound. Jamming "all the wires into the 12v lines and turn it on" is pretty much what you'll be doing.

All of the devices are 12V devices, so no problem there with varied supply voltages. You'll drive them all in parallel- all of the 12V positive supply lines tied to the positive PS output, and all of the negative supply lines tied to the negative input.

The power supply is rated for 40 amps, and the ~36 amps you'll be drawing should not be excessive (but it may be too close to the PS rating for reliable, long term survival).

As far as how to actually connect these- there are a lot of options. [Terminal strips](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Eaton/TB100-02B/?qs=9GX7soZQXxEK%252bmTEfqoXFg%3D%3D&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI7seo0uLp2AIVgUsNCh1nsQBkEAQYAyABEgKASfD_BwE) with [spade lugs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0002ZPG7K) and jumpers would be my simplistic solution assuming I had the room.

Comment: So if my understanding of the theory is correct, even if they're drawing power from the same connector (and their wires are all touching one another), each device will only draw what it needs? So long as they're all 12v and not connected in series?

Comment: Yes... That's correct